# Gmail checker stopped working since yesterday

Tags: firefox, gmail

I'm in a bit of an hassle, i got Gmail Checker for Firefox, both updated to the latest version, it was working fine since yesterday, and last night it start'ed to gave me errors connecting to my gmail accounts.

At first it was only the gmail account with i got 2-step verification activated, (which happened before) so, i revoged the last application password and got a new one, but it still didn't work.

I was left with only one account after inexplicably one of them disconnected automatically without saying anything, the real problem is, the account i was left with, i pressed "Logout of all accounts", tried to connect to that same account, and it failed, though it was checking email fine in that account just before... does anyone have the same problem?

I'm kinda stuck with Gmail Checker since i don't know anymore extensions for FF that does this job.

EDIT: I Also tried to reinstall the add-on, but, i don't know how to do a clean install since the last account was logged-in after i did the reinstallation... (I was hoping it would delete all the data)
I also disabled my firewall, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments on the add-on page, i found out the last version was broken, so, i installed version 2.6.1 and everything seems to work again, except i can't seem to get 2-step verification working, will attempt later since i apparently have exceeded the limit of sms per day or something.